# JAVA SimpleDateFormat on ArrayList changes Date

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter

I'm populating a 'ListView' with an 'ArrayList' using an Adapter.
The 'ArrayList' contains objects with date and time.
When i send the data as it is to the ListView, there is no problem, and the list shows the relevant objects as desired :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  TimePeriod freeSlot = (TimePeriod)getItem(position);

  if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView start = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    TextView end = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end);

    startTime = freeSlot.getStart().toString()      
    endTime = freeSlot.getEnd().toString();
    start.setText(startTime);
    end.setText(endTime);

    return convertView;
}
```

> 2017-07-05T10:30:00.000Z 2017-07-05T11:30:00.000Z

But when i use SimpleDateFormat to change the output as i want, it somehow sets the dates of all objects to the same one (01/01) :

```
startTime = freeSlot.getStart().toString();
endTime = freeSlot.getEnd().toString();

try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            Date newDate = formatter.parse(startTime);
            Date newDate2 = formatter.parse(endTime);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM hh:mm");
            startTime = format.format(newDate);
            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            endTime = format1.format(newDate2);

        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

        start.setText(startTime);
        end.setText(endTime);
```

> for start - 01/01 10:30, for end - 11:30

As iv'e mentioned earlier, all objects get this date even though dates & hours are different.

Any ideas? What am i doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you date contain 12 or  24-hour format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> See java.text.SimpleDateFormat API, pattern letter y: For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits.

Comment: Thank you very much! All i did was changing 'YYYY' to 'yyyy' and it works! so simple...

Answer (score 0):

use something like this to make it easy,
Create a util class with Below Methods:

```
 /**
     * Parses @date to String in provided @format
     *
     * @param date   Date
     * @param format Convert to Format
     * @return formatted date string
     */
    public static String DateToString(Date date, String format) {
        if (date != null) {
            try {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                return dateFormat.format(date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses date to String in provided format
     *
     * @param date   Date
     * @param format Convert to Format
     * @return formatted date string
     */
    public static String DateToString(Date date, Format format) {
        if (date != null) {
            try {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format.format);
                return dateFormat.format(date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Create static enum/String Format for Reusability. such as below :

```
 public static enum Format {

        /**
         * "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT1("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "dd/MM/yyyy"
         */
        FORMAT2("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        /**
         * "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT3("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
         */
        FORMAT4("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),
        /**
         * "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
         */
        FORMAT5("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
        /**
         * "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         */
        FORMAT6("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
        /**
         * "dd-MM-yyyy"
         */
        FORMAT7("dd-MM-yyyy"),
        /**
         * "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT8("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
         */
        FORMAT9("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),
        /**
         * "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
         */
        FORMAT10("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"),
        /**
         * "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         */
        FORMAT11("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
        /**
         * "MM/dd/yyyy"
         */
        FORMAT12("MM/dd/yyyy"),
        /**
         * "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT13("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
         */
        FORMAT14("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),
        /**
         * "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
         */
        FORMAT15("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"),
        /**
         * "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         */
        FORMAT16("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
        /**
         * "MM-dd-yyyy"
         */
        FORMAT17("MM-dd-yyyy"),
        /**
         * "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT18("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
         */
        FORMAT19("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),
        /**
         * "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
         */
        FORMAT20("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"),
        /**
         * "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         */
        FORMAT21("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
        /**
         * "yyyy/MM/dd"
         */
        FORMAT22("yyyy/MM/dd"),
        /**
         * "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT23("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a"
         */
        FORMAT24("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a"),
        /**
         * "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
         */
        FORMAT25("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"),
        /**
         * "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
         */
        FORMAT26("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
        /**
         * "yyyy-MM-dd"
         */
        FORMAT27("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        /**
         * "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
         */
        FORMAT28("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"),
        /**
         * "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"
         */
        FORMAT29("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"),
        /**
         * "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
         */
        FORMAT30("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"),
        /**
         * "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
         */
        FORMAT31("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        private String format;

        private Format(String format) {
            this.format = format;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return format;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to use either HH:mm or hh:mm a THis is difference between 24 and 12 hour format.

Comment: You need to use either HH:mm or hh:mm a THis is difference between 24 and 12 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

change it to :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

you need to

You need to use either HH:mm or hh:mm a THis is difference between 24 and 12 hour format.